# Tag for not-so realistic worlds

Tags: discussion, tags

Parody is big part of writing and the parodies itself take place in a worlds. While we have [science-based](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-based) and even [hard-science](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hard-science), I am missing some tag which would tell everyone, that I am not searching for really realistic solutions, but for plausible, or even funny ones.

I am proposing tag [parody](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parody) or [parody-based](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parody-based) to clearly say what is the setup of the question

**Edit** Proposed tag wiki:

> For questions which do not require exact scientific reasoning, but rather a fun explanation why such question could work

**Edit2** Basically, what I am looking for is to give idea in how serious the answer should be. And best by having a tag for it

Comment: Could you [edit] this question to include a proposed tag wiki, at least the summary, that describes how you feel this tag should be used? I don't quite see how what you are proposing, particularly the "plausible" part, is very different from [reality-check](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reality-check) in practice, or even the absence of any of reality-check/science-based/hard-science, with or without a further explanation in the question body. It would also be good if you could give some examples of the types of people who might want to follow such a tag.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this needs a tag.

The main reason for this is you are actually making it harder for people reading the question to know what sort of answer is expected. Unless they see the tag **and know what it means** then they could well go in completely the wrong direction.

In this sort of situation I think you just start the question with something like:

> I'm writing a hitch-hiker's guide style comedy and

or

> I'm writing a romantic comedy set in a world where

or

> I'm writing a spoof sci-fi show that sends up star wars and

This both informs people that it's a parody world and gives them real information as to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It might just be my opinion, but fun is, to some extend, subjective.

Then either you suggest some possible answer and wants to see if it is somewhat plausible. And then, the tone indicates where you stand.

Or you're asking for a typical idea generation and that would probably be closed out as *too broad*.

Either way, I'm not much of a fan of the idea.

Comment: Basically, what I am looking for is to give idea in how serious the answer should be. And best by having a tag for it

Comment: @PavelJanicek Considering how few actually respect the requirements for answering `science-based` and `hard-science` questions already, what makes you feel your proposed tag would fare better? As opposed to simply stating in the question body something like "bonus points for answers that make me chuckle".

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Sometimes I have the feeling, that from question itself it is not clear if asker wants serious or funny answers. So I thought having tag  to clearly say "you can be fun here" would be good idea. But anyway thanks for feedback. I am also growing to realization that its not as good idea as I originally thought

Comment: @PavelJanicek No worries. We all have ideas sometimes that sound good at first, but upon closer examination turn out to be not quite so good. It's better to float the idea here on Meta first if you are uncertain; it doesn't really cost you anything (except a bit of time) and we all get to chime in on whether (and why) it is good or bad.